# Query mutiple fields from a nested document of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB 3.0.5. I have a collection like

```
db.getCollection('mytest').insert([
{_id: 1, "records": [{"Name": "Joe", "Salary": 70000, "Department": "IT"}]},
{_id: 2, "records": [{"Name": "Henry", "Salary": 80000, "Department": "Sales"}, {"Name": "Jake", "Salary": 40000, "Department": "Sales"}]},
{_id: 3, "records": [{"Name": "Sam", "Salary": 90000, "Department": "IT"}, {"Name": "Tom", "Salary": 50000, "Department": "Sales"}]},
{_id: 4, "records":[{"Name":  "Janice", "Salary": 80000, "Department": "Finance"}, {"Name": "Kale", "Salary": 95000, "Department": "IT"}]}
])
```

Now I could query a single field, say like people in the IT department -

```
> db.getCollection('mytest').find({"records.Department": {"$in": ["IT"]}}, {"records.$": 1})
{ "_id" : 1, "records" : [ { "Name" : "Joe", "Salary" : 70000, "Department" : "IT" } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "records" : [ { "Name" : "Sam", "Salary" : 90000, "Department" : "IT" } ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "records" : [ { "Name" : "Kale", "Salary" : 95000, "Department" : "IT" } ] }
```

I really want to find the salaries in the departments of Finance and IT.
But the query with more than one fields returns part of the desired results -

```
> db.getCollection('mytest').find({"records.Department": {"$in": ["IT", "Finance"]}}, {"records.$": 1})
    { "_id" : 1, "records" : [ { "Name" : "Joe", "Salary" : 70000, "Department" : "IT" } ] }
    { "_id" : 3, "records" : [ { "Name" : "Sam", "Salary" : 90000, "Department" : "IT" } ] }
    { "_id" : 4, "records" : [ { "Name" : "Janice", "Salary" : 80000, "Department" : "Finance" } ] }
```

I wonder if somebody could help with it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: I have seen this post, which is based on one query field. My question is about multiple fields. I am not sure if Mongo 3.2 has solved the similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using mongodb [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) operator. Try the following code:

```
db.getCollection('mytest').aggregate([
  {  $match: {'records.Department': {$in: ['IT', 'Finance']}}},
  {  $project: { 
      departments: {
        $filter: { 
          input: '$records', 
          as: 'record', 
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {$eq: ['$$record.Department', "IT"]}, 
              {$eq: ['$$record.Department', "Finance"]}
            ]
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For your data I got the following result:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "departments" : [ { "Name" : "Joe", "Salary" : 70000, "Department": "IT" } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "departments" : [ { "Name" : "Sam", "Salary" : 90000, "Department": "IT" } ] }    
{ "_id" : 4, "departments" : [ { "Name" : "Janice", "Salary" : 80000, "Department" : "Finance" }, { "Name" : "Kale", "Salary" : 95000, "Department" : "IT" } ] }
```